# PHP Documentation not working in Aptana

Tags: php, aptana

I have installed **Aptana Studio 3**, set my workspace as `C:\wamp\www` and set project nature only to `PHP - primary`. Everything is working (for ex. autocomplete from extended class) but PHP documentation simply is not working. I added some function like

```
/**
 * Test
 */
public function error($status_code, $message = null) {
    ....
}
```

but when I hover it (I saved the file) I get `No available documentation`? Where is the problem? :/

I'm on Windows 7 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

The hover will not work when you are on the `error` word at the function declaration (a bug).

It should work for you when you call the `error` function. You should see the documentation-hover when you code assist, and also see similar info when you hover the word.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't see it :/ Whenever pops out some info window I get "No available documentation". I saved the file, used GIT and commited and still nothing. http://i.stack.imgur.com/GSyMl.jpg

Comment: Hmm, what version are you on? You can sync to the latest by grabbing updates from the 'release' or 'development' branches. See http://preview.appcelerator.com Also, try to do a project->Clean (all) from the menu.

Comment: I tried all three, stable first, beta second and nightly. The problem stays :/